# @Email annotation not working in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-annotations, spring-validation

I have a getMapping controller which accepts emailId and Set as input.
I want to have a validation check for Non empty/blank values and email id validation, below is the sample code. @Email validation is not throwing any error for invalid input. Also if i pass "  " @NotEmpty or @NotNull or @NotBlank is not throwing error.

Also @Pattern is not applied to all values in Set and custom error message is not displayed

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Validated
public class TestController {
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ReturnType method(@Email @RequestParam("email") String email, @Pattern(regexp = "", message ="")Set<String> values) 
    {
     //code..
    }
```

Comment: When in doubt consult the docs - [email](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Email.html), [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html). There you will see that the default regex for email matches any string, `null`s are valid as well. Pattern on the other hand is applicable on `CharSequence`s (string, etc.), it won't work on a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument

[https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation#:~:text=Of%20course%2C%20the%20most%20relevant,Validator%20%E2%80%94%20and%20validates%20the%20argument](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation#:%7E:text=Of%20course%2C%20the%20most%20relevant,Validator%20%E2%80%94%20and%20validates%20the%20argument).